# SQL mutiple line update improve query

Tags: sql

I have 500+ SQL update statements that need to be performed on a large table. The update statements take several minutes to execute just for one member. As of now I have to stop & update each portion of every update statement.
I need to run these in a more efficient way if possible to speed up the completion process. I have a spreadsheet with address etc that need to be updated in the table.

I need to change the PRBTADC, PRSTADCD, & STADDRCD to either;  S-"CITY NAME"  , F-"CITY NAME" , PF-CITY NAME" , P- "CITY NAME". 
Ideally I'd just like to change the CUSTNMBR & "s,f,pf,p" status once instead of 3 separate lines.

Here is an example of what I'm doing

[image]

```html
SELECT * FROM [N].[dbo].[RM00101]
where CUSTNMBR ='21'
SELECT * FROM [N].[dbo].[RM00102]
where CUSTNMBR ='21'

select 
--a.*,
b.DEX_ROW_ID,a.PRBTADCD,a.PRSTADCD, a.STADDRCD, b.USERDEF1, b.* 
from RM00101 a
inner join RM00102 b on a.CUSTNMBR = b.CUSTNMBR
where a.CUSTNMBR ='21'

update rm00102
set
ADRSCODE = left('PF-MISSOULA',15)
where 
CUSTNMBR = '21'
and ADRSCODE = 'PRIMARY'


update RM00101
set
PRBTADCD = left('PF-MISSOULA',15)
where 
CUSTNMBR = '21'
and ADRSCODE = 'PRIMARY'

update RM00101
set
PRSTADCD = left('S-WAREHOUSE',15)
where 
CUSTNMBR = '21'
and ADRSCODE = 'PRIMARY'

update RM00101
set
STADDRCD = left('PF-MISSOULA',15)
where 
CUSTNMBR = '21'
and ADRSCODE = 'PRIMARY'
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated as this is a tediousprocess.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you update several columns in one update statement? like:

```
update RM00101
    set ADRSCODE = left('PF-MISSOULA',15)
    ,PRBTADCD = left('PF-MISSOULA',15)
    ,PRSTADCD = left('S-WAREHOUSE',15)
    ,STADDRCD = left('PF-MISSOULA',15)
    where CUSTNMBR = '21'
    and ADRSCODE = 'PRIMARY'
```

Comment: So just copy the statement and change the table. Work done

Comment: Should have just changed rows you selected: with custnmbr = '21' and adrscode = 'Primary'